# Android checkbox in listview doesn't check

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a listview of checkboxes, but when in code I select them on the screen they remain unselected. What do I do wrong? Here is [an Android Studio project](https://github.com/yaroslav-ulanovych/checkbox-doesnt-check).

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

                View checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                checkBox.setSelected(true);

                assert checkBox.isSelected();

                return view;
            }
        };

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.add("foo");
    }

}
```

Activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setChecked(true) instead of setSelected(true)

Comment: Shame on me. Facepalm.

Answer (score 1):

you should get checkBox as CheckBox in getView method of adapter via cast then call setChecked(true) method